# A command line utility to test the status of files in iCloud drive directory

Tags: terminal, icloud, filesystem

Is there a command-line program that determines the status of files (uploaded, uploading, ineligible, etc) in the iCloud drive?

For example, I would like to be able to use a program such as `find` to get a list of files that have not been successfully uploaded to iCloud drive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `brctl status`.

It outputs alot, but you can grep pretty easily, for example `brctl status |grep needs-sync-up |cut -d'"' -f2` will show you all files waiting for being uploaded (without their path), or use `brctl status |grep 'somefile.ext'` for checking the status of somefile.ext.

See `brctl --help` for more.

Comment: On macOS Monterey, this `brctl` command is no longer readable. I haven’t yet figured if it’s an intentional change or there’s just more clutter when files are all synced (false positives to be filtered out)